# Use php var in javascript file fault

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

I have a question about using a php variable in my javascript file.
This is my **index.php** file:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['appid'])) {
                        // GET appid
                        $appid = $_GET['appid'];

                        $json_url  ='http://api.url.com/api/gateway/call/1.4/getApp?appid=' . $appid;

                        $ch = curl_init($json_url);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                        $str = curl_exec($ch);
                        curl_close($ch);

                        $data = json_decode($str);
                        $array = json_encode($data);
                    }  

                    else{

                    }    
                ?>
                <p id="errors" class="text-error"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js.php"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see I check if an appid is sent. When I received it I load data from an api.
In the bottom of the page I have a link to my javascript file. (.php because I want to use the php var $ array in my js file)

My **main.js.php**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = <?php echo $array;?>;
    alert(data);
});
```

But I got always error in console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Comment: is it the full source of `main.js.php`? the code you pasted here you sets `$array` in your `index.php`  and tries use it in your `main.js.php` ?

Comment: The `$array` variable from your `index` file is'nt available in your `main.js.php` file.

Comment: Can I load my data from api in .js.php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the array **in a completely different file!** The two variables are not in the same scope. What's more, the Javascript file is apparently not interpreted as PHP (and neither should it). So:

1. Javascript complains about the `<?` tag, which it should never see.
2. Even if you solved that, it won't work since there's no PHP `$array` variable in `main.js.php`.

Start by understanding how Javascript and PHP are interpreted, see [Reference: Why does the PHP code in my Javascript not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work).

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is in a different scope since you're not using the PHP `include` function. Here's the easiest way I know to achieve what you want:

- Rename your JavaScript file to `main.js`
- Since you cannot use PHP in a `.js` file, declare your JavaScript variable before you call your script, like this:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var array = '<?php echo $array ?>';
  </script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  ```
- Then, in your `main.js` file, just replace the code you posted by this:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var data = array;
      alert(data);
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = '<?php echo isset($array) ? $array : 
                    json_encode(array("nothing in array data"));?>';
    // if $array not set then it should return {"0":"nothing in array data"}
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I still get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Remove the `curl code` from your page then check if error comes then there no error in `javascript`.

Answer (score -2):

you forgot to Quote Value of var data use this

```
var data = '<?php echo $array;?>';
```